# Getting 401 error when placing HTTP request in Flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow, power-automate

I'm trying to write a Flow that gets a list of emails from the Finance Managers list to send an email to. When I get to the HTTP Request to query the Finance Managers list, it throws a 401 error- access denied. The list I'm querying is of course on SharePoint Online (O365). Do I need to do something like creating an app step and authorizing the Flow like I had to do with SharePoint Designer workflows? If so, how do I do that with a Power Automate Flow?

Comment: Do you have the access on SharePoint list? Can you please add any screenshot or something of the configuration you made for HTTP request? It will be easier to find error in configuration if any.

Comment: I am one of the Site Collection Admins for the site. I have Full Control of the list. I don't have screen shots to share because I switched the flow to query the data using the "Get SharePoint List Data" action instead of "Send HTTP Request to SharePoint". I found a query on a Microsoft forum where someone said that basically HTTP Requests don't work with SharePoint from Flow.